# Batching a python script with multiple iterations at multiple arguments

Tags: python, batch-file

I would like to run my python script with multiple arguments with a batch file.  My script currently needs 3 input arguments and I want two of the arguments to change after finishing the previous run. The process would be something like this

```
 python test.py 5 5 10
```

though I would like to have the first argument to run from 5 to 20 and after that, the second argument increments by one until 10 so it'll be something like this

5 5 10

6 5 10

...

20 5 10

5 6 10

6 6 10

...

20 10 10

I apologize if it's a very simple procedure but I'm extremely new to creating batch files. Also I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /l %%f in (5 1 20) do for /l %%s in (5 1 10) do python test.py %%f %%s 10
```

Wheren `for /l` iterate over the numeric indicated set: `start step end`

`for` replaceable parameters (`%%f` and `%%s` in sample code) use double percent signs inside batch files (the percent is doubled to escape it). From command line, use a single percent sign.